# Delete Relationship Key in EF 4 with repository pattern and DbContext

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, generics, entity-framework-4, repository-pattern

I`m using ASP.NET MVC, Sql Compact Edition, Entity Framework 4 with generic repository pattern with DbContext.
I have some problem when I want to delete one entity which has child or delete entity with many-to-many relationship.

I got error : 
The operation failed: The relationship could not be changed because one or more of the foreign-key properties is non-nullable. When a change is made to a relationship, the related foreign-key property is set to a null value. If the foreign-key does not support null values, a new relationship must be defined, the foreign-key property must be assigned another non-null value, or the unrelated object must be deleted.

There are bunch posts explained it, but I`m stuck because the example is many explained without repository pattern or using ObjectContext.

here is some my code at repository base and way I use it.

```
 public abstract class RepositoryBase<T> : IRepository<T> where T : class
{
    private readonly DbContext _context;
    private readonly IDbSet<T> _dbset;

    protected RepositoryBase(DbContext dbContext)
    {
        _context = dbContext;
        _dbset = _context.Set<T>();
    }

    public void Delete(T entity)
    {
        _dbset.Remove(entity);
        Commit();
    }

    private void Commit()
    {
        try
        {
            _context.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch (DbEntityValidationException dbEx)
        {
            var exceptionMessage = new StringBuilder();
            foreach (var validationErrors in dbEx.EntityValidationErrors)
            {
                foreach (var validationError in validationErrors.ValidationErrors)
                {
                    exceptionMessage.AppendFormat("Property: {0} Error: {1}", validationError.PropertyName,
                                               validationError.ErrorMessage);
                }
            }

            throw; //so that we see the exception right away when we develop
        }
    }
```

and the service calls it :

```
public class UserService : IUserService
{
    private readonly IUserRepository _userRepository;

    public UserService(IUserRepository userRepository)
    {
        _userRepository = userRepository;
    }

    public void DeleteUser(User user)
    {            
        _userRepository.Delete(user);

    }

    public void DeleteUser(int userId)
    {
        var user = _userRepository.GetById(userId);
        DeleteUser(user);
    }
}
```

I mean, can we just call delete service from repository and all the child object is automatically delete?or if I have to delete the child entity one by one, how I could do that?
and I dont wanna modify the database with using cascade because when I changed model and generate database from model it will broken all.

UPDATE : here is the model

```
public partial class User
{
    public User()
    {
        this.EAConnections = new HashSet<EAConnection>();
        this.UserRepositoryRoles = new HashSet<UserLinkRepositoryRole>();
    }

    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<EAConnection> EAConnections { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<UserLinkRepositoryRole> UserRepositoryRoles { get; set; }
}

public partial class UserLinkRepositoryRole
{
    public int UserRepositoryRoleId { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public int RepositoryRoleId { get; set; }
    public int EAConnectionId { get; set; }

    public virtual User User { get; set; }
    public virtual RepositoryRole RepositoryRole { get; set; }
    public virtual EAConnection EAConnection { get; set; }
}
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: What do you mean, that if you change the model and generate the database, everything will be broken? What's going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

When you map the entities in EF you need to enable "Cascade Delete" so that when a parent is deleted all the children are deleted.

```
HasRequired(child => child.Parent)
   .WithMany(parent => parent.Children)
   .HasForeignKey(child => child.ParentId)
   .WillCascadeOnDelete();
```

If you are modeling an existing database make sure the foreignkey is set up with "Cascade Delete".

Comment: is it possible if we just modify repository pattern code?not modeling?

Comment: @Rivera You would have to delete each child entity before you delete the parent. That would be a terrible solution :)

Comment: why it would be terrible? and I have posted my model so if you dont mind, please change the answer based on my model :)

Comment: @Rivera You are trying to solve the problem in the wrong layer. You would have to go though each of the child items and delete them(you may miss child entities). If you added a different child collection in future you have update the logic again.